# Can't remove file $$$222.php left behind by attacker

Tags: linux, file, ssh

My website was recently hacked and had a number of malicious files on the server.  They all had the -i and -a  extentions added to them

I found this out using 
`lsattr` command and then used
`chattr -ai <Filenames>` to remove the immutable and append only attributes
Then `rm -f <Filenames>` to remove

All good

However there is one file 
`$$222.php` which cannot be removed

When I do anything with the filename `$$222.php` it returns

```
No such filename or directory whilst trying to stat 761022.php
```

How can I delete this file?

Comment: `$` probably means a variable to your shell, try puting the file name in single quotes `rm '$$$222.php'`.

Comment: Possibly, `$$` is converted to the process id number by your shell.

Comment: Don't believe that by simply removing some of these malicious files you have overcome the attack. *You probably should re-install from scratch and hunt code injections

Answer (score 1):

This is easily duplicated.

```
mkdir SO
cd ./SO
echo > '$$$222.php'
ls
$$$222.php
```

OK we have one of these, and if you try to rm...

```
rm $$$222.php
rm: cannot remove ‘351522.php’: No such file or directory
```

We can confirm that the `$$` is transformed by the shell to the process ID number.

```
ps

PID TTY          TIME CMD
3515 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
7671 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
```

Turns out 3515 is just bash's process id number or PID, which occurred because the shell transforms $$ to the PID.

```
echo $$
3515
```

And it becomes 351522 not 3515222 because `$2` refers to the 2nd argument to the command `bash` which was blank.

You can use `rm -i` with a wildcard to remove it, and the `-i` will ask you if you are sure you want to remove each matching file:

```
rm -i *php

rm -i *222.php
```

Or you can use single quotes, `rm '$$$222.php'`

Double quotes `rm "$222.php"` will still be transformed by the shell and will be transformed where it will not match.

Comment: Thanks Paul - I'd tried double quotes before I went to sleep but never did single quotes  Its gone .  It appears that no oither files were changed during the hack either - was able to trace the hack to a time on the 21st of january when the files were injected - however nothing else on the server was changed on or after that time